# PDO UNION function only processes first SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pdo, union

Okay so I have three different types of users (Developers, Designers & Employers) all of whom have different database tables. I have successfully developed a script that can log in a user from any of the three user tables using UNION. However I have now introduced email verification on sign up so I need to test whether the 'confirmed' field (in each table) has a value of '1' to process a successful login (if the value is 0, the user will not be able to log in).

```
    public function email_confirmed($email) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT 
            COUNT(developers.id) FROM " . DB_NAME . ".developers WHERE developers.email=  ? AND developers.confirmed = ? 
            UNION SELECT COUNT(designers.id) FROM " . DB_NAME . ".designers WHERE designers.email = ? AND designers.confirmed = ? 
            UNION SELECT COUNT(employers.id) FROM " . DB_NAME . ".employers WHERE employers.email = ? AND employers.confirmed = ?
            ");
        $query->bindValue(1, $email);
        $query->bindValue(2, 1);
        $query->bindValue(3, $email);
        $query->bindValue(4, 1);
        $query->bindValue(5, $email);
        $query->bindValue(6, 1);

        try{

            $query->execute();
            $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

            if($rows == 1){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

At the moment however (using the function below), only a developer can log in. If you attempt to log in using a designer or an employer account, the error below shows. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
 if ($users->email_confirmed($email) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, but you need to activate your account. Please check your emails.';
    } else // carry on logging in user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(developers.id)
FROM " . DB_NAME . ".developers
WHERE developers.email=  ? AND developers.confirmed = ? 
UNION
SELECT COUNT(designers.id)
FROM " . DB_NAME . ".designers
WHERE designers.email = ? AND designers.confirmed = ? 
UNION
SELECT COUNT(employers.id)
FROM " . DB_NAME . ".employers
WHERE employers.email = ? AND employers.confirmed = ?
```

It is fetching three rows, then removing duplicates, and ordering them arbitrarily.  You are then reading the value (the count) from one of these rows.

Taking the approach you are taking, I think you want:

```
select COUNT(*)
from ((select 1
       from " . DB_NAME . ".developers
       where developers.email=  ? AND developers.confirmed = ? 
      ) union all 
      (select 1
       from  " . DB_NAME . ".designers
       where designers.email = ? AND designers.confirmed = ? 
      ) union all
      (select 1
       from " . DB_NAME . ".employers
       where employers.email = ? AND employers.confirmed = ?
      )
     ) t
```

Comment: Perfect! Would you recommend using alias' for each table in this statement or do you think thats overkill?

Comment: @jshjohnson . . . I am generally a fan of using aliases, so `d` for `developers` and so on.  However, in terms of readability, it would have minimal impact on this query.